# Background Color keep updating on click or scroll

Tags: javascript, android, angular, ionic-framework

I have a function to Generate Background Colors (working fine) but the issue is when i click anywhere on the screen or sometimes even scrolling the page changes the background colors again and again.

HTML:

```
<ion-button shape="round" color="clear" [ngStyle]="{'background':getRandomColor(), 'border-radius': '20px'}" *ngFor="let c of categories;">{{c.title}}</ion-button>
```

.ts

```
 getRandomColor(){
    let color = "#";
    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        let part = Math.round(Math.random() * 255).toString(16);
        color += (part.length > 1) ? part : "0" + part;
    }
   return color;    
  }
```

Now every time user clicks on buttons or anywhere on screen colors getting auto changed and that's annoying.
Also I am getting this error in my Console.

```
ProfilePage.html:44 ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'background: #de5d88'. Current value: 'background: #2ce111'.
    at viewDebugError (core.js:20440)
    at expressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError (core.js:20428)
    at checkBindingNoChanges (core.js:20530)
    at checkNoChangesNodeInline (core.js:23401)
    at checkNoChangesNode (core.js:23390)
    at debugCheckNoChangesNode (core.js:23994)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:23922)
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (ProfilePage.html:44)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:23911)
    at checkNoChangesView (core.js:23289
```

EDIT:
Categories are coming from server for selection.

```
this.categories= [
 "Horror1"
 "Horror2"
 "Horror3"
]
```

Comment: That's because change detection is triggered at user interaction, so `getRandomColor` is being invoked every time. You should set the background color once. Please share more of your codebase (including the part of how you define the `categories`) in order to be able to provide a solution.

Comment: Categories Sample added to Question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because change detection is triggered at user interaction, so `getRandomColor` is being invoked every time. You should set the background color once.

```
// Some place where categories are defined
this.categories = this.categories.map(category=> ({...category, bgColor: this.getRandomColor()}));
```

```
<ion-button shape="round" color="clear" [ngStyle]="{'background': category.bgColor, 'border-radius': '20px'}" *ngFor="let c of categories;">{{c.title}}</ion-button>
```

Comment: I had this Idea to reinitialize categories array with color object in it, but i am looking for better solution. though i did this and it worked. but if you have better solution please discuss.Because sometimes there are 1000+ categories and subcategories and doing them in this way i think is not good.

Answer (score 0):

Please create a model with data and color and then set in adapter, In your case when you scroll it then onBindViewHolder is called and generate new color again.so use randomcolor() method in class not in adapter.